# How to disable dropdown option?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu

I have simple data like this,

```
const data = {
  games: {
    type: [
      { id: 1, value: "Indoor" },
      { id: 2, value: "Outdoor" }
    ],
    sport: [
      { id: 1, value: "Tennis" },
      { id: 2, value: "Chess" },
      { id: 3, value: "Football" }
    ]
  }
};
```

With the help of this data, I am in the need to make dropdown. But I have some **precondition** based on which I need to enable or disable the options in the respective dropdown.

**Precondition**

[image]

**Requirement:**

Based on the above give precondition,

-> If user selects *Indoor* from *dropdown 1*, then inside *dropdown 2* the value of *Tennis and Football* needs to be **disabled**.

[image]

-> If user selects *Outdoor* from *dropdown 2*, then inside *dropdown 2* the value of *Chess* needs to be **disabled**.

**Vice Versa scenario**

User can also select first option from the dropdown 2 as well,

-> If user selects *Chess* from *dropdown 2*, then inside *dropdown 1* the value of *Outdoor* needs to be **disabled**.

[image]

-> If user selects *Tennis or Football* from *dropdown 2*, then inside *dropdown 1* the value of *Indoor* needs to be **disabled**.

**Working sandbox**

[image: Edit React Typescript (forked)]

Also I am open to modify the above given data to achieve the expected result.

Kindly help me how to modify the above given data to **disable** the respective dropdowns on selection of respective options in the respective dropdown.

Stuck for very long time, any good help would be appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't have enough information in your object. You need some way of knowing that `Chess` is an `Indoor` sport and `Tennis` and `Football` are `Outdoor` sports

Comment: @Nick, Yes you are right, I have the above data alone for now but I am  **open to modify the above data** as per the requirement.

Comment: I'd probably make the `sport` property an array in each of the `type` properties e.g. `type: [ { id : 1, name : 'Indoor', sports : [ { id: 1, name : 'Chess' }] }, ... ]`. But it really depends on what else you want to do with the data...

Comment: @Nick, I have made an update with the question with an image, Here we don't remove the option from the dropdown instead we only disable it. So I believe based on your suggestion, if user selects `Indoor` then only `Chess` will be value for dropdown 2 but I also need to have `Tennis` and `Football` as well in dropdown 2 but in **disabled** state.

Comment: @Nick, It is kind of vice versa as well, User can also make first selection in `dropdown 2`,  For eg.., if user select `Chess` in `dropdown 2` then in `dropdown 1` , we need to disable `Outdoor` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simplistic plain JS code to do basically what you want. I'm CW'ing this as it's not complete.

```js
const data = {
  games: {
    type: [
      { id: 1, value: "Indoor", sportId: [2] },
      { id: 2, value: "Outdoor", sportId: [1, 3] }
    ],
    sport: [
      { id: 1, value: "Tennis", typeId: 2 },
      { id: 2, value: "Chess", typeId: 1 },
      { id: 3, value: "Football", typeId: 2 }
    ]
  }
}

const typeSelect = document.getElementById('type')
const sportSelect = document.getElementById('sport')

const createSelect = (values, select) => {
  values.forEach(t => {
    let opt = document.createElement('option')
    opt.value = t.id
    opt.text = t.value
    select.append(opt)
  })
}

createSelect(data.games.type, typeSelect)
createSelect(data.games.sport, sportSelect)

typeSelect.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  const val = e.target.value
  const type = data.games.type.find(t => t.id == val)
  Array.from(typeSelect.querySelectorAll('option')).forEach(o => o.disabled = false)
  Array.from(sportSelect.querySelectorAll('option')).forEach(o => o.disabled = true)
  type.sportId.forEach(sId =>
    sportSelect.querySelector(`option[value="${sId}"]`).disabled = false)
})

sportSelect.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  const val = e.target.value
  const sport = data.games.sport.find(s => s.id == val)
  Array.from(sportSelect.querySelectorAll('option')).forEach(o => o.disabled = false)
  Array.from(typeSelect.querySelectorAll('option')).forEach(o => o.disabled = true)
  typeSelect.querySelector(`option[value="${sport.typeId}"]`).disabled = false
})
```

```html
<select id="type">
</select>
<select id="sport">
</select>
```